# MeteorでIron Routerを使うとFoundationのドロップダウンメニューが動かない

Tags: meteor, iron-router

マウスカーソルをのせても、クリックしてもドロップダウンメニューが開きません。やったこと：

プロジェクトを作ってパッケージを追加:

```
$ meteor create dropdown-test
$ cd dropdown-test
$ meteor add iron:router ewall:foundation
```

`dropdown-test.html`にFoundationのドロップダウンメニューを[サンプル](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html)からコピペ:

```html
<template name="layout">
  <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
    <section class="top-bar-section">
      <ul class="right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Right Button Active</a></li>
        <li class="has-dropdown">
          <a href="#">Right Button Dropdown</a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Active link in dropdown</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </nav>
  <div id="main" class="row">
    {{> yield}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="hello">
  Hello world!
</template>
```

`dropdown-test.js`にルーティング情報を追加

```js
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});

Router.route('/', {name: 'hello'});
```

meteorを実行

```sh
$ meteor
```

各バージョン:

- meteor: 1.0
- ewall:foundation: 5.4.6
- iron:router: 1.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[別のFoundation用パッケージのReadme](https://github.com/juliancwirko/meteor-zf5)に書かれているように、ルーティング後にFoundationを初期化するようにする必要があります。

たとえば`dropdown-test.js`に以下を足します。

```js
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    if (typeof(Router) !== 'undefined' && Router.onAfterAction) {
      Router.onAfterAction(function () {
        Tracker.afterFlush(function () {
          $(document).foundation('reflow');
        });
      });
    } else {
      UI.body.rendered = function () {
        $(document).foundation('reflow');
      };
    }
  });
}
```

ルーティングとは無関係にテンプレートがレンダリングされることがある場合は、そのテンプレートの`rendered`コールバックで初期化を制御できます。

```js
Template.alert.rendered = function () {
  // alertプラグインのみ初期化
  $(document).foundation('alert', 'reflow');
};
```